# jquery how to select div

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have script that append sections(div) to my page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 1;

        $('#AddSectionButton').click(function () {
            $('div#bottomLeftContent').append(
            '<div  id="section" class="listItem">' +
                '<table class="sectionTable">' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td style="width: 20%; padding:0;">' +
                            '<p>' + counter + ':' + '</p>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td style="width: 70%; padding:0;  ">' +
                            '<p>Label<p>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td style="width: 10%">' +
                            '<img alt="" src="Images/noselected.png" class="selectImage" />' +
                        '</td>' +
                   '</tr>' +
                '</table>' +
         '</div>');

            counter++;


        });
});
```

and i want to select only one section - when i click on it, i want to change background  and src for image. And only one section can be selected. How can i do this?

i try to use something like this:

```
$('.listItem').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('selectedItem');
            //                $('#section').css('background-color', '#D7D7D7');
            //                $('#section > img').attr('src', 'Images/Selection.png');
        });
```

But it not work correctly.

Comment: The function looks fine to me. Maybe your div is collapsed and therefore not clickable? Use Firebug or similar tool to make sure your div is occupying the area you think it does.

Comment: This script select only the first block, and toggle class for it, but not next blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you're adding many of these, then you don't want to put `id="section"` in the added divs. This would add many of the same id in the page, and you don't want that. That item already has the class `listItem` and you're using that for the click target, so you don't need the id at all - remove it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;

    $('#AddSectionButton').click(function () {
        $('div#bottomLeftContent').append(
        '<div class="listItem">' +
            '<table class="sectionTable">' +
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td style="width: 20%; padding:0;">' +
                        '<p>' + counter + ':' + '</p>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 70%; padding:0;  ">' +
                        '<p>Label<p>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 10%">' +
                        '<img alt="" src="Images/noselected.png" class="selectImage" />' +
                    '</td>' +
               '</tr>' +
            '</table>' +
     '</div>');

        counter++;


    });
});
```

Then in your `.listItem` click handler, you need to target things correctly. Try this:

```
$('.listItem').live('click', function () {

    // first revert any selected items back to initial state
    $('.selectedItem').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
    $('.selectedItem').find('img').attr('src', 'Images/noselected.png');
    $('.selectedItem').removeClass('selectedItem');

    // now mark the clicked item as selected
    $(this).toggleClass('selectedItem');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#D7D7D7');
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'Images/Selection.png');

});
```

Comment: I've updated my answer - assuming you want to only have one item with `.selectedItem` at a time. When you click on an item, you remove the class `.selectedItem` from all items, then add yours. See my updated answer and implementation in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swatkins/PGjPj/

Comment: I remove id and this example works like a previous. But class 'selectedItem' can be applied only for one div, now i can apply it for many divs. When i select one div  - others must be deselected. How do this?

Comment: I've updated the answer to revert all selectedItems back to initial state, then change the selected item:  updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swatkins/PGjPj/1/

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('.listItem').live('click', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('selectedItem');
            //                $('#section').css('background-color', '#D7D7D7');
            //                $('#section > img').attr('src', 'Images/Selection.png');
});
```

**EDIT**:

Delegate version:

```
$('#bottomLeftContent').delegate('.listitem','click', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('selectedItem');
});
```

Comment: You should currently use .delegate() instead of .live() for performance reasons, but keep your eyes on the .on() and .off() functions:
http://blog.jquery.com/2011/09/28/jquery-1-7-beta-1-released/

Comment: This works better thanks!But how to select only one div at the moment.Now i can select all of blocks.

Comment: You might want to use `delegate` instead of `live` for performance reasons.

Comment: Check out @swatkins answer. Especially what he says about the `id`.

Comment: When you click a div, do you want only the clicked div to toggle, or all?